# How do I run a python script and files located in an aws s3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have python script pscript.py which takes input parameters -c input.txt -s 5 -o out.txt. The files are all located in an aws s3 bucket. How do I run it after creating an instance? Do I have to mount the bucket on EC2 instance and execute the code? or use lambda? I am not sure. Reading so many aws documentations kinda confusing.

Command line run is as follows:

```
python pscript.py -c input.txt -s 5 -o out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You should copy the file from Amazon S3 to the EC2 instance:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/pscript.py
```

You can then run your above command.

Please note that, to access the object in Amazon S3, you will need to assign an IAM Role to the EC2 instance. The role needs sufficient permission to access the bucket/object.

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the purpose of AWS? How will you run that in an ec2 instance?

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the EC2 instance. I've updated my answer.